# FULL OUTER JOIN - mysql

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, first table is called 'submissions' and the second table is called 'area'

```
********  SUBMISSIONS TABLE  ********
userid  statusid  no      name    area    month    year    dateupdated
62      2         763     ABCD    Brazil      6    2013    2013-11-26 15:28
62      1         869     ABC     Brazil      7    2012    2013-11-26 15:10
62      2         869     ABC     Brazil      6    2013    2013-11-26 15:28
62      1         869     ABC     Brazil      6    2013    2013-11-26 14:50
61      1         763     ABCD    Brazil      6    2013    2013-11-26 14:50
54      1         200     ABCDE   US         12    2013    2013-11-26 21:02
32      2         200     ABCDE   US         12    2013    2013-11-26 21:03
```

```
******* AREA TABLE ********
  no      name    area     
  763     ABCD    Brazil  
  869     ABC     Brazil  
  869     ABC     Brazil  
  869     ABC     Brazil  
  763     ABCD    Brazil  
  200     ABCDE   US      
  200     ABCDE   US
```

My Process:

- A user selects a status
- A user selects a month
- A user select a year
- All via dropdowns (SELECT)

Once they have selected the 3 fields, the filtered data is displayed.

What I am trying to achieve:

I want the records to show as per the SELECTS Above (this works correctly at the moment)
I also want to show all records from the 'Area' Table and where no data exists in the 'Submissions' table. An example of my desired output is below:

```
userid  statusid  no      name    area    month    year    dateupdated
62      2         763     ABCD    Brazil      6    2013    2013-11-26 15:28
62      1         869     ABC     Brazil      7    2012    2013-11-26 15:10
62      2         869     ABC     Brazil      6    2013    2013-11-26 15:28
62      1         869     ABC     Brazil      
                  763     ABCD    Brazil      
                  200     ABCDE   US        
                  200     ABCDE   US
```

In Summary, I need to show the selected records as the SELECTS, but also need to display all records from the area table.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a left outer join here. Basically you want to select all records from area table and the matching rows from submission table.

The query would look like -

```
select sb.userid, sb.statusid, a.no, 
       a.name, sb.area, sb.month, 
       sb.year, sb.dateupdates 
  from area a left outer join submission sb
    on (a.no = sb.no)
```

Comment: That is invalid SQL (and not a left join either)

Comment: Thanks for answering but i do not see LEFT OUTER JOIN? i have tested it and it doesnt work unfortunately.. Anyone have any solutions please?

Comment: sorry, I have modified the sql, I missed to type left outer join

Comment: When you add the WHERE to your statement it will only reflect the selected fields. It does not show all records

Comment: which condition are you adding in where clause ?

Comment: As from above:

My Process:

    A user selects a status
    A user selects a month
    A user select a year
    All via dropdowns (SELECT)

Once they have selected the 3 fields, the filtered data is displayed

But i also need to display all other fields where there is no data for the above selections.